# How to give a security group access to cloudwatch and s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I want to create a security group linked to my vpc in aws.
But I am not able to figure out, how shall this security group be given access to specific aws services through inbound and outbound rules.

For Ex. Security Group which would have S3 and CloudWatch Access.

Preferably in terraform. Please help here any links or references.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Security Group which would have S3 and CloudWatch Access.

You can't do that. You can only allow generic https outbound connections in your SG.

However, if you were to use [VPC interface endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpce-interface.html) for S3 and CW, then you could use SG referencing to restrict which SG can connect to the endpoints.